# mysql off-site replication ( file only )

Tags: java, mysql, replication

I am new to mysql, I have extensive experience with MS Access and some with Tivoli. I have tried to search the net for my solution but there is such a massive quantity of results I can't find a solution. My question is a two part.

1. What I need to do is to have mysql operate two database files, the first would be a normal setup, the second would not. I need the second file to be on a remote file system, possibly on my google drive. I would somehow need to create the db locally then xfer it to the gdrive, then have mysql connect to the shared url.
2. Part two: mysql will need to have full two replication between the two db files. I want to be able to delete records on the gdrive file. I know how to do this in Access but I have no idea how to do this in mysql. The server is behind several NAT's and can only make outbound connections, I cannot change this. I will be using Java for input/reading/maintenance. On the server side Java will work normally. On the gdrive side, will the server be able to handle java making deletions directly?

Can this be done? Any thoughts and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* work.  But you probably need to have a separate instance of mysqld running on your machine, using the cloud "drive" as the directory for holding the mysql files.

Assuming you now have two instances of mysqld running on the *same* machine (your machine), they would need to be segregated -- either by being in different VMs, or by using different "ports".  (3306 is the default port; some use 3307 or 4306.)

Then set up replication.  I would make your mysql on your machine with 3306 be the Master and the "drive" instance be the Slave.

If you try this, please report back on whether it worked or what issues you had.